# Issues of creating a new form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

In the button click even handler of Form1, I want to create Form2. Here is my code,

even handler of button1 of Form1

```
// button1 belongs to Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2("www.google.com");
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form2 contructor

```
public Form2 (string str)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    address = str;
    button2.Text = str; // button2 belongs to Form2
}

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

My question and concern is, button 1 event handler is executed by Form1's UI thread, and if I create new Form2 inside the Form1 UI thread, and use the UI thread to set Form2's UI element (button2.Text), is that legal? My understanding is each Form has its owner UI thread and UI elements (e.g. button) should be processed only by the forms individual owner thread? If my code is wrong, appreciated if anyone could show me what is the elegant way to creat another Form inside event handler of the current form and pass parameters.

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is perfectly fine. Both forms will live in the same thread and can access each other without worrying about threading. No new threads are spawned unless you specifically say so, in this case.

As a side note, I would want to alter your constructor of `Form2` a little bit. I assume that `Form2` also has the default constructor with no parameters, and that that constructor also calls `InitializeComponent`? If so, there is no need to duplicate that call in your constructor; if you set it up like this, it will first run the default constructor, and then you add your custom stuff:

```
public Form2 (string str) : this()
{
    address = str;
    button2.Text = str; // button2 belongs to Form2
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, I have posted my another constructor of Form2, and it has only one line of code to call InitializeComponent. Are there any functional bug of my code (if I just keep my code as it is now showed in my original post) compared with yours?

Comment: No, there is no bug or antyhing technically wrong with the code. It's only a matter or avoiding code in different places doing the same thing; removing redundancy, nothing else.

Comment: Does it mean no matter how many Forms I create, in a Windows Forms application, all of the Forms will share the same single UI thread?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (as Tormod Fjeldskår indicates below). The number of forms is not a factor, everything happens on the same thread.

Comment: Mentioning the `: this` for the constructor makes this answer perfect!

Answer (score 2):

In Winforms, all UI elements within an application share the same UI thread. So rest assure, there is nothing wrong with your code in that sense.

Comment: You mean no matter how many Forms I create, all of them will share the same UI thread?

Comment: That's right. All forms belonging to the same application will share the same UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal and should work just fine.

Comment: I want to know no matter how many Forms I create, all of them will share the same single UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

And the second form will use the same thread as form1

Comment: Does it mean no matter how many Forms I create, in a Windows Forms application, all of the Forms will share the same single UI thread?

Comment: yes.
only way the new form will be on another thread is if you create the form using the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally legal :-) Documentation only says that any UI control should be only accessed  from the thread on which it was created.

Comment: Does it mean no matter how many Forms I create, in a Windows Forms application, all of the Forms will share the same single UI thread?

Comment: as mliesen said "All forms will run on the same thread, (unless you start a new thread and created the form within this thread)."

Answer (score 1):

All forms will run on the same thread, (unless you start a new thread and created the form within this thread).

Comment: Does it mean no matter how many Forms I create, in a Windows Forms application, all of the Forms will share the same single UI thread?